# Issue upgrading Parse SDK

Tags: sdk, parse-platform

I'm trying to upgrade my Parse app from version 1.2.19 to 1.6.1, but I receive errors on virtually every file. My procedure is as follows:

1. Remove the old framework from my project folder.
2. Remove references to framework.
3. Unpack new frameworks into the same root folder of Project.
4. Re-link against the framework.
5. Clean & build.

However, I never get to build as I encounter errors on all files. For example, in my PFQueryTableViewControllers' `- (id)initWithCoder` method, none of the properties like `self.parseClassName` are recognized even though I can successfully command-click on the `<Parse/Parse.h>`  I've followed the steps mentioned [here](https://parse.com/questions/sdk-upgrade-on-ios) and [here](https://parse.com/questions/what-is-the-best-way-to-rollout-new-parse-changes) to no avail. Am I alone or just a dunce? Don't answer that. Seriously though, any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the PFQueryTableViewControllers have moved locations and I needed to:

```
#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>
```